# SSO with spring security kerberos/NTLM and fetch additional details from AD

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, active-directory, spring-security-kerberos

I want user to be authenticated by using its windows login credentials without explicitly showing him login page. The user will just login to his machine and when we will try to open the url he will be authenticated by spring security using his windows login credentials and data related to his role will be fetched from AD. How can I achieve this? 
Adding to this question, what I need to do if machine is non-window? say CentOS?

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve that?